# How to iterate over JSON response in JSP?

Tags: java, json, jsp, servlets

I have created a servlet which is creating a Json response as follows:

```
JSONObject jsonObj      = new JSONObject();
JSONArray  arr = new JSONArray();

       for (int i=0 ; i<2 ; i++)
       {
           temp = new JSONObject();
           temp.put("value" , i+1);
           temp.put("string " , i+1);
           arr.put(temp);
       }
       jsonObj.put("finalList", arr);
       temp= new JSONObject();
       temp.put("emp", 5);
       temp.put("sal", 1000);

       jsonObj.put("dept",temp);

       response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        req.setAttribute("depRes",jsonObj);
        RequestDispatcher dispatch= req.getRequestDispatcher("process.jsp");
        dispatch.forward(req, response);
```

Basically, it is making JSON response like below:

```
{
"finalList": [
   {
      "value" : 1,
      "string": 1
   },
   {
      "value" : 2,
      "string": 2
   }

   ],
"dept":{
     "emp": 5,
     "sal":1000
   }
}
```

Now I want to take this JSON response into my JSP file and put only "finalList" values in a table like below:

```
Value    String  
-----    -------
1        string 1
.............
```

I don't know how to take the JSON object passed as response from servlet and process it  in JSP. Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: you can either do this with javascript or with JSTL. The easier option would be JSTL.

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte Can you show me how to do this in JSTL?

Comment: Have you used jstl before? Are you on maven?

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte I haven't used it before.

Comment: Okay i can help you with that but first you need to fix your json object. It's making a stackoverflow error.

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte What do you mean? As the code is working fine.

Comment: Okay then can you include a string representation of your json ? Because i can an error running that.

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte I have updated my question to show the json result that I am generating

Comment: Define "process it in JSP". If you're making like a REST API call from JavaScript you'll process the response in JavaScript as well.

Comment: @DaveNewton Processing here means the JSON response that I am sending from the servlet to JSP should be displayed in the `<table>` in JSP as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @ABeginner You're missing the essential question: how are you planning on getting this data? You're returning `application/json` which makes me thing you're making an XHR request, which means you're making the call via JS/Ajax. Which means you're getting the response in JS, which means you'll be creating your DOM in JS via the success handler.

Comment: @DaveNewton Sorry, for not understanding it properly. You are right in guessing that. The problem is I am pretty new to JSP and servlets and so, I don't have any idea how to get this JSON response that is sent by the servlet.

Comment: @ABeginner JSP has nothing to do w/ processing Jax JSON responses--that's JavaScript. You *could* return HTML (e.g., the results of running through your data, not in JSON format, through a JSP) and simply insert it into a DOM element, although I don't know as I'd recommend it (but I wouldn't explicitly advocate against it, either). You might want to take a step back real quick and determine your actual needs/requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse it with javascript:

```
var obj = JSON.parse('${requestScope.jsonObject}');
```